# How to increment the result of a calculation inside a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I have a loop, and every time the result of Y - X is greater than or equal to 1000, I want another variable (Z) to increment by 30. So every time the difference between Y and X increases by 1000, Z increases by 30. so:

```
3000 - 2000 = 1000, so Z = 30
3500 - 2000 = 1500, so Z = 30
4000 - 2000 = 2000, so Z = 60
4500 - 2000 = 2500, so Z = 60
5000 - 2000 = 3000, so Z = 90
```

Hopefully, that makes it clearer
etc...

I can't figure it out, any ideas?

```
    while (Y >= X)
        {
            while (Y - X **==** 1000)
            {
                Z += 30;                    
                break;
            }
            result = (Y - X) + Z;
            break;
        }
```

Obviously i know that doesn't work, and isn't tidy, I can't think how to do it

Comment: What is `X`? What is `Y`? What's the loop you have?

Comment: X and Y are two numbers inputted by the user

Comment: And what does the loop do? Input new values each time?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: This is way too basic and trivial. Anyway: `if ((Y - X) >= 1000) Z += 30;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (Y >= X)
{
  Y = Y - X;
  if (Y >= 1000)
  {
    Z += 30;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int y = 1000;y<= 10000;y+=1000)
{
   for(int x = 1000;x< = 10000;x+=1000)
    {
          if(y-x>=1000)
            z+=30;
     }
}
```

If my understanding is correct,the above code should increment z by 30 whenever (y-x) is greater than or equal to 1000. Initialise z to 0 outside the loops.